# Magento products gallery

Tags: php, collections, magento

i don't know if my title is ok, but what i'm trying to do is something like a gallery or at least my client call it this way...lol..... i'm trying to do something like the seach result page but without a search criteria, without a filter, just click in a link and see a list of products, with the same funcionality, change the view mode(Grid, List), select the amount of products to show and a pager, i need some help here, what I've done so far is, i create a new controller with just one action as simple as

```
public function listAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

in my xml layout

```
<catalog_products_list>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_uhmalist" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="additional">
                    <block type='enterprise_search/suggestions' name='search_suggestions' template="search/suggestions.phtml"></block>
                    <block type='enterprise_search/recommendations' name='search_recommendations' template="search/recommendations.phtml"></block>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                <action method="setPageLayout"><layout>three_columns</layout></action>
            </block>
            <action method="setListOrders"/>
            <action method="setListModes"/>
            <action method="setListCollection"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_products_list>
```

it is almost identical to catalogsearch_result_index block in catalogsearch.xml, when i tried to go to my new page it show me no products, the collection was empty, so, i change the content of funcion _getProductCollection() in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php for this

```
if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5);
        $productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
        $this->_productCollection = $productCollection->load();
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
```

i don't like to change the core code, but now i'm trying to make it work, so, when i refresh the page it show me the products, i can change the view mode, i can see the amount of products, but, the pager don't work, when i change the amount of product i whanna show, it do nothing, just change the label 8 Item(s) for Item 1-8 of 8, and doesn't group it, if i pick 5, it should show just 5 items, but i can see the 8 i have in my db, so,

what is wrong with my code?, how can i make the pager work??
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer myself.

I was doing some wrong steps in the XML layout. I changed

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

to

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

and I changed this line to the default value

```
<block type="catalog/product_uhmalist" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

to

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

Now everything is working, even the pager. Anyway, thanks to everyone who read my post